# How to make ClamAV check every file I download automatically and display something noticeable if it contains something harmful?

Tags: software-recommendation, chromium, downloads, antivirus, clamav

Can I make ClamAV check files I download (using Chromium) automatically and display a popup or something noticeable if it is harmful?

Or is there a better program for doing this?

Comment: Start with this https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/20/automatically-detecting-files-placed-in-my-downloads-directory-in-gentoo-linux-and-scanning-them-for-viruses/ and https://github.com/astroidmail/astroid/wiki/Opening-attachments-and-virus-detection and post any problems you have

Answer (score 0):

If you do `clamscan --remove=yes -i -r ~/`, it should delete all viruses automatically, but I'm new to Linux so I'm not 100% sure. Sorry if this wasn't the answer you where looking for.